# Referencing a Numerical Value From a Cell in Excel VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

For the code below, I want the value of "x" to be variable based on the values of cells in Excel, say the years 2000 and 1995. Given these two years, I want the value of "x" to be 5 (2000 - 1995). I have tried a few different things, but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
Dim i As Integer 
For i = 1 To 5 
    rng.Select 
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select 
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/R122C" 
Next i
```

Comment: You want the difference in years of a range of dates?

Comment: `For` goes with a `Next`, it's a block. Everything between `For` and `Next` is the loop body. What are you trying to achieve? Why does `i` need to start at `1`? We need more information about what you're trying to do in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, so essentially I have trend factors for each year. In this example, 2000 would be the first year that I have the trend for and 1995 would be the first year that I need the trend. So I would need to execute the following code 5 times to calculate the trend values of the past 5 years:

Dim i As Integer
     For i = 1 To 5
        rng.Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C/R122C"
        Next i
        End If
        Next

Comment: And each of these years is in their own cell. So 2000 is in C12 and 1995 is in C13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of possibilities are endless as to ranges you want to loop.  You can create variables and perform functions to find whatever numbers you want to find.  You can count, sum, etc.  Be aware that variables have limits (Integer versus Long).  In the example below I created a `MinYear` and `MaxYear` assuming that the range contained years.  If it was dates, you would have to find the formula to extract years.  You can use results to define the loop or do the math to find the difference as suggested.

```
Sub LoopOnCellValues()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MinYear As Integer
    Dim MaxYear As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    MinYear = WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(2, 100)))
    MaxYear = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(2, 100)))

    For i = MinYear To MaxYear
        'do something
    Next i

    'or

    For i = 1 To (MaxYear - MinYear)
        'do something
    Next i

End Sub
```